# m2m field 'through' another model that contains two of the same fields

Tags: django, django-models

The basic idea is that I want to track training and have a roster for each training session. I would like to also track *who* entered each person in the roster hence a table rather than just an M2M to the Member model within Training.

So, here is what I currently have:

```
class Training( models.Model ):
   name = models.CharField( max_length=100, db_index=True )
   date = models.DateField( db_index=True )
   roster = models.ManyToManyField( Member, through='TrainingRoster' )

class TrainingRoster( models.Model ):
   training = models.ForeignKey( Training )
   member = models.ForeignKey( Member )

   ## auto info
   entered_by = models.ForeignKey( Member, related_name='training_roster_entered_by' )
   entered_on = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )
```

The problem is that django doesn't like the "roster=models.m2m( Member, through='TrainingRoster') as there are two fields in TrainingRoster with a ForeignKey of Member.  I understand why it is unhappy, but is there not a way to specify something like: through='TrainingRoster.member'.  That doesn't work, but it seems like it should.

[I will admit that I am wondering if the "entered_by" and "entered_on" fields are the best for these models. I want to track who is entering each piece of information but possible a log table might be better than having the two extra fields in the TrainingRoster table. But that is a whole separate question.  Though would make this question easier. :-) ]

Comment: I am surprised there is no answer or even thoughts.  Is there a better way i could do this?  One thought would be to create an Entered model that would gave the Member, date etc.